# When my SEO text slug in the URL ends with a dot symbol, I get a 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Quite strange!

Here is the custom route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Dota2-News-Details", // Route name
            "dota2-news/{id}/{slug}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Dota2News", action = "Detail", slug = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Working links:

```
http://localhost:20099/dota2-news/3/Some-random-post
http://localhost:20099/dota2-news/5/Another-random-post
http://localhost:20099/dota2-news/14/New-delicious-items
```

Non-working links:

```
http://localhost:20099/dota2-news/4/The-Dark-Moon-comes.
http://localhost:20099/dota2-news/11/Bwa-ha-welcome.
```

On a whim, I went in the database and modified the SEOTextSlug to remove the final `.` symbol from the value. As expected, it now works properly. I'm confused though, I thought URL's could end with a `.` symbol.

Here's my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id, string slug)
{
    var viewModel = new OfficialNewsModel();
    var news = _officialNewsRepository.FindById(id);

    if (news.SEOTextSlug != slug)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Dota2News", new { id = news.OfficialNewsId, slug = news.SEOTextSlug });
    }

    viewModel = Mapper.Map<OfficialNew, OfficialNewsModel>(news);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

My question:

Why does the trailing `.` symbol, break the app? A URL can't have a doy symbol anywhere in it?

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /dota2-news/1/In-defense-of-the-Temple.
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A URL can't have a doy symbol anywhere in it?

It can. Not at the end though out-of-the-box.

So to allow it add the following to your `web.config` (`<system.web>` section):

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

[Haacked blogged](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx) about it. [Hanselman also](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx). If you are a .NET developer and haven't yet subscribed to those 2 blogs and read them on a daily basis you will probably miss lots of useful things.