# WebApi Attribute Routing for URLs with *.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

OK it's not *that* funny an ending...

I am trying to emulate a RoR-based service in .Net WebAPI.  The Ruby implementation of the service is supposed to return a JSON document from a url of:

```
http://myserver/api/assessments/{id}.js
```

Note the `.js` at the end.

I made a `RouteAttribute` decoration on my api controller like so:

```
[Route("~/api/assessments/{id}.js")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAssessment(int id)
{
    . . .
}
```

...but I'm getting a 404 error.  I suspected this might be because the request ended in "js", so after a bit of research I found I should set my `RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles` to `true`... this did not seem to have any effect.  I am still getting 404.

Am I right?  is the `.js` ending what is causing the 404?  How can I get around this?  This is a pure WebApi project, so it's not like I'm using JavaScript in it anyway.

Comment: This may be of help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494200/can-periods-be-used-in-asp-net-web-api-routes Read the section on constraints.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to keep this "extension" on your service endpoint?  This should never be necessary in Web API since you can content-negotiate to return JSON.

Comment: [Route("~/api/assessments/{id:int}.js")] and your config should have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true.

Comment: Well, like I said, I'm trying to emulate the service from RoR... that's what the service is expecting.

Comment: The route debugger can be really helpful:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/ 
I'd suggest posting those results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the following in your Web.config? I recently just setup Routing for a project for Work and this line caused me all sorts of hell because it was not present:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    ...
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The .js extension may not be getting picked up by the managed modules that do the routing.

Addendum:
Additional data that is within that configuration section and required to make it work:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
               System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode"
        verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
        type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
              System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
              PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests may have performance impacts on your application.

Comment: hmm... that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: That is very true, it may be a considerable alternative to instead map .js files in IIS to run through ASP.NET modules.

Comment: Did you replace the existing <modules> line? (or add the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" property to the tag?) I omitted the closing tag from it in the original answer, but it's not a one-line tag.

Comment: No I already had a modules tag, so I just added the attribute.

Comment: Ah alright, have you guaranteed (through breakpoints) that the 404 is IIS server-side, and not application side?

Comment: nvm, once I recycled my IIS Express instance, this worked.  Thanks!