# web api optional parameter before extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am using web api 1 mvc 4

I have following code

```
public void save(int id , string name, string code = "")
{

}
```

I have following mapping in webapi.config.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "saveproduct",
                 routeTemplate: "api/product/save/{id}/{name}/{code}.{ext}",
                 defaults: new
                 {
                     controller = "product",
                     code = RouteParameter.Optional,
                     action = "save"
                 });
```

Now If I call

> localhost://api/product/save/1/book/p23.json

It works

But

> localhost://api/product/save/1/book/.json

It does not work

The reason I found is because optional parameter "code" is in between.

How can I make it work.. As I need extension must at the end with optional parameter like "code".

I found [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494200/can-periods-be-used-in-asp-net-web-api-routes) , but could not got anything related.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Short**: you can't.

**Long**: you can't have an optional parameter in the middle of route because the system is not able to understand if the ".json" is the value of your *{code}* or the value of your *{ext}* parameter.

If you want to use this kind of approach you need to force the code parameter always.

BTW, a route like *localhost://api/product/save/1/book/.json* has no sense... .json it's like a "file" extension, but there is no file name here. You shouldn't allow this kind of call.