# Uri.EscapeDataString or HttpUtility.UrlEncode does not work for my case

Tags: c#, .net, urlencode

I have an API in a project which I coded as following:

```
[Route("api/SearchCustomer/{customer}")]
[HttpGet]
public List<Customer> SearchCustomer(string customer)
{
    return customerRepo.GetSearchJoined(customer);
}
```

At first, I got an issue when I am calling this API from my front end, if customer contains dot or space(for example: https://www.somesite.com/walmart Inc.), I will get 404 error(cannot found this API). I find an easy way to solve this problem. Just add a "/" will solve this problem.(https://www.somesite.com/walmart Inc./ )

Now I need to call this API in another project at the back end. So I did something like this:

```
var urlParm = "https://www.somesite.com/api/SearchCustomer/" + name + "/";
response = client.GetAsync(urlParm).Result;
var dataObjects = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Customer>>().Result : null;
return dataObjects;
```

Unfortunately, adding the "/" at back does not work. I am still getting 404 error. Then, I tried to use Uri.EscapeDataString or HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode "name".([Does C# have an equivalent to JavaScript's encodeURIComponent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86477/does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent))

```
name = Uri.EscapeDataString(name)
or name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name)
or name = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(name)
var urlParm = "https://www.somesite.com/api/SearchCustomer/" + name + "/";
or var urlParm = = "https://www.somesite.com/api/SearchCustomer/" + name
response = client.GetAsync(urlParm).Result;
var dataObjects = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Customer>>().Result : null;
return dataObjects;
```

I have tried all the different matches of above code. All of them did not work. I am still getting the 404 error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Sorry for the typo, I removed some sensitive information so I deleted the "api" by mistake. The route is not the problem. I have tested that the api call from the back end worksif name contains only letters or numbers but fails when name contains dot.

Comment: Shouldn´t it be [Route("api/SearchCustomer/{customer}")]???

Comment: "Then, I tried to use Uri.EscapeDataString or HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode "name"." What was the output?

Comment: MVC routes don't care where the HTTP request comes from, only about the URL. If the local call fails, it means the URL is wrong - your route doesn't start with `api/`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I did have api in the code. I have tested, if the name is sth like "wal". The api works fine.

Comment: if you have a local environment, you should use localhost. Do you know for sure if what is published on your site contains that structure to consume the api?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494200/can-periods-be-used-in-asp-net-web-api-routes#answer-19870684

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not relevant the `customer` parameter is encoded or not. You should specify the routing and apply the request correctly. Firstly fix the route;

```
[Route("api/SearchCustomer/{customer}")]
```

Then apply the request.

```
https://www.somesite.com/api/SearchCustomer/samplecustomer
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have tested that the api work if the name is sth like "wal"

Comment: If the name contains "."